# Delete an object in array by id nodejs , javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having issues deleting an object by id in an array(database).

``````
route.delete('/:id', (req, res) =>{
let match = false
for(let i=0; i< database.posts.length; i++){
if(id == database.posts[i].id){
match = true;
database.posts.splice(id, 1)
}
return res.json({status: 'Success', message : 'Entry deleted'}
}
}
if(!match){
return res.json('Cannot delete entry')
}
} )

`````
``````

In my database I have a list of object with its unique id (1- 10) , meaning the index is (0-9). The code work fine when I start deleting by id fromthe end of the array . But when I delete from the middle of the array ,it delete another posts instead. For example , if I delete an object with id 3 (index 2), afterward  trying  deleting an object with id 4, the code deletes object with id 5 instead because there's been a change in the index .

```
Please can I better improve this code to work appropriate?
```

Comment: loop from the end to start... or you need to set i to be one less when you make the deletion.

Comment: You need to splice at the index `i` but you are passing the `id`. `database.posts.splice(i, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
route.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    let match = database.posts.findIndex(post => post.id === req.params.id)
    if (match < 0) // not found returns -1
        return res.status(404).json({ status: 'error', message: 'Entry ID not found' })
    
    database.posts.splice(match, 1)
    return res.json({ status: 'success', message: 'Entry deleted' })
})
```

Comment: Thank you..Please how can I update an array aside using splice()?

Comment: `````route.patch('/:id', (req,res)=>{
 const {id} = req.params
 const {title, description} = req.body
 let match = false
 for(let i = 0; i < database.Posts.length; i++){
 if(id == database.Posts[i].id){
 match = true
 let updatedEntry = database.Posts[i].id
  updatedEntry = ({id:id, title:title, description:description})
  database.Posts.splice(id , 1, updatedEntry)
 return res.json({status:"Success entry successfully updated!", data:updatedEntry})
 }
 }
 if(!match){
   return res.json('Cannot find entry')
 }
 })

Comment: You can just assign the properties to `database.posts[match]`, like `database.posts[match].title = title` and so on.